# Subtract a number from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to subtract from revlength each time the loop occurs. e.g if there are 2 'A Google user' posts then subtract 2 from revlength

this is what I tried.

```
var revlength = place.reviews.length;
if(place.reviews[index].author_name == 'A Google User') {
    $("#revnum").html(revlength--);
}
```

upon adding to the script, the code does not work for

```
$.each(place.reviews, function (index, value) {
        if (place.reviews[index].text.length != 0) {
            if (place.reviews[index].text.length == 0) {
                $("#revnum").html(--place.reviews.length);
            }
            if (place.reviews[index].author_name == 'A Google User') {
                $("#revnum").html(--place.reviews.length);
                var imgid = '<img src="img/gplus.gif" width="50" height="50">';
            } else {
                $("#revnum").html(revlength);
                var imgid = '<img src="img/user.gif" width="50" height="50">';
            }
```

Comment: You're not changing `place.reviews.length;` so if this is in a loop, then `revlength` will just have the same value everytime.  It looks to me like you need to `--place.reviews.length;`.  You should probably show more of the code around this.

Comment: the loop begins on line2, for example i have 2 'a google user' posts

Comment: also jfriend00 i think that worked!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to show the count of reviews excluding reviews where author_name = A google user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var revlength = $.grep(place.reviews, function (val) {
    return val.author_name !== 'A Google User';
}).length;
// alert(revlength);
// console.log(revlength);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this..

change

```
$("#revnum").html(revlength--);//you are doing post-decrement
```

to

```
$("#revnum").html(--revlength);//you need to change it pre-decrement.
```

If other parts are going right , then it will work sure.

**Explanation:**

--i and i-- where the position of the -- determines whether one is subtracted before or after the value is used.

if  i-- the value will be used before decremented.
if  --i the value will be used after decremented.

Comment: Post decrement (eg - revlength--) will first gives the value of revlength and then it decrement the value of revlength. Pre decrement (eg : --revlength) will first decrement the value of revlength and then will gives the decremented value.

Comment: Makes sense. But the last line in your answer needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment (that appears to have worked) into an answer:

You need to actually decrement `place.reviews.length`.

```
if(place.reviews[index].author_name == 'A Google User') {
    $("#revnum").html(place.reviews.length--);
}
```

Your original code was only decrementing a temporary variable `revlength` which was not persistent because you would just reload that variable from `place.reviews.length` each time.  Thus `place.reviews.length` never got decremented.

---

By way of explanation, perhaps you were under the impression that after doing:

```
var revlength = place.reviews.length;
```

That when you then did:

```
revlength--
```

that it would also decrement `place.reviews.length`, but that is not the case.  `revlength` is a new variable that was set to have the value of `place.reviews.length`, but when you do `revlength--`, that only changes that variable and doesn't have any effect on `place.reviews.length`.  So, for the decremented value to persist, you need to decrement `place.reviews.length`.

Comment: If `place.reviews` was an array won't this code truncate the array?

Comment: @SalmanA - yes, if it was an array, it would truncate the array.  The OP would have to show more of their code to know what solution was best.  I assumed it was just a number.  If it's an array and they don't want to change the array, then they need to get the length once outside the loop into another variable and decrement only that variable.  We do the best we can with the partial context that is shared in the question.

Comment: @SalmanA - The point of this answer is that they need to decrement something that is initialized outside the loop, not something that is initialized inside the loop because decrementing what they were inside the loop does not persist since they simply overwrite the decremented value the next time through the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one,

```
var revlength = place.reviews.length;
revlength =  parseInt(revlength.toString());
if(place.reviews[index].author_name == 'A Google User') {
revlength--;
$("#revnum").html(revlength);
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you convert the number to string and back to a number again?

Comment: this make sure your variable in integer and then you can easily perform increment and decrement actions on that variable